# How to mouse left click on webelement in a field using webdriver in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

### I am unable to upload webpage image.

FileSection: -> is field name

### Windows8.1-KB254622325.exe ->is file name added into field

Remove and select are buttons to the field.
when we select file name by mouse left click, file name highlighted and Remove button enabled(highlighted),then only we can remove exist file name and add new one.
HTML code :

### Filed Section:

Windows8.1-KB254622325.exe

### Remove and Select buttons:

Comment: can you provide HTML for the fields in question

Comment: HTML code :
Filed Section:
--------------
<select class="standard-selection-3" onchange="FileSectionChanged();" size="8" multiple="multiple" name="FileSection">
<option value="90ddb13f-0989-4433-a17f-4b6438f02f78">Windows8.1-KB254622325.exe</option>
</select>

Comment: Remove and Select buttons:
----------------------------
<input class="button_font" type="button" onclick="sendAction(document.forms[0].editFileAction, 'removeFiles');" value="Remove" name="btnRemoveFileName">

<input class="button_font" type="button" onclick="sendAction(document.forms[0].editFileAction, 'selectFileName')" value="Select File" name="btnSelectFileName">

Comment: Please edit your question and provided HTML code instead of providing it to comment..

Comment: intially i pasted in question section but i don't its not showing